# Javascript mouse up event triggers very late

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mouseup

I have a [jquery sorting plugin](http://camohub.github.io/jquery-sortable-lists/) which works pretty fine, but if I make few dragging operations the **mouseup** event starts to be very slow. It takes about 1 second while it triggers the event. If I dump end of mousemove event it stops immediately but mouseup event starts after the second. I added the console.log() for every method in the code but there is no call between drag stop and mouseup. What could be the 
problem? How can I debug possible parallel processes in the browser? The code looks like:

```
    ....
        state.doc
            .on( 'mousemove', dragging )
            .on( 'mouseup', endDrag );

    }

    /**
     * @desc Start dragging
     * @param e event obj.
     */
    function dragging( e )
    {
        ...

        console.log('dragging end');
    }


    function endDrag( e )
    {
        var cEl = state.cEl,
            hintNode = $( '#sortableListsHint', state.rootEl.el ),
            hintStyle = hint[0].style,
            targetEl = null, // hintNode/placeholderNode
            isHintTarget = false, // if cEl will be placed to the hintNode
            hintWrapperNode = $( '#sortableListsHintWrapper' );

        if ( hintStyle.display == 'block' && hintNode.length && state.isAllowed )
        {
            targetEl = hintNode;
            isHintTarget = true;
        }
        else
        {
            targetEl = state.placeholderNode;
            isHintTarget = false;
        }

        offset = targetEl.offset();

        cEl.el.animate( { left: offset.left - state.cEl.mL, top: offset.top - state.cEl.mT }, 250,
            function()  // complete callback
            {
                tidyCurrEl( cEl );

                targetEl.after( cEl.el[0] );
                targetEl[0].style.display = 'none';
                hintStyle.display = 'none';
                // This has to be document node, not hint as a part of documentFragment.
                hintNode.remove();

                hintWrapperNode
                    .removeAttr( 'id' )
                    .removeClass( setting.hintWrapperClass );

                if ( hintWrapperNode.length )
                {
                    hintWrapperNode.prev( 'div' ).append( opener.clone( true ) );
                }

                var placeholderNode = state.placeholderNode;
                // Directly removed placeholder looks bad. It jumps up if the hint is below.
                if ( isHintTarget )
                {
                    placeholderNode.slideUp( 150, function()
                    {
                        var placeholderParent = placeholderNode.parent();
                        var placeholderParentLi = ( ! placeholderParent.is( state.rootEl.el ) ) ? placeholderParent.closest( 'li' ) : null;

                        placeholderNode.remove();
                        tidyEmptyLists();

                        setting.onChange( cEl.el );
                        setting.complete( cEl.el ); // Have to be here cause is necessary to remove placeholder before complete call.
                        state.isDragged = false;

                        if( setting.maxLevels !== false )  // Has to be after placeholder remove.
                        {
                            recountLevels( cEl.el );
                            if( placeholderParentLi ) recountLevels( placeholderParentLi );
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    state.placeholderNode.remove();
                    tidyEmptyLists();
                    setting.complete( cEl.el );
                    state.isDragged = false;
                }

            } );

        scrollStop( state );

        state.doc
            .unbind( "mousemove", dragging )
            .unbind( "mouseup", endDrag );

    }

    ....
```

Here https://camo.publicvm.com/ I made an example with dumps for all methods in the code. Look at the latency of endDragggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg log. Also I checked this issue in Opera browser and it has no problem with it.

**EDIT:** I think the problem was in local variables in the closure in animate call. var placeholderNode, var placeholderParent and var placeholderParentL. As I rewrite it to global state object problem is gone.

Comment: I tested the live example but I wasn't able to reproduce the error: the `endDragggggggggggggg` message appear in the console as soon as (from a human perception point of view) I release the mouse button. Is there a specific test case to reproduce the error or you simply solved it rewriting as global state objects the said variables? By the way.. gratz! Very nice!

Comment: Hmm so it seems it is the problem in my browser. Good. Thank you.

Comment: I can confirm, no issue in latest Chrome on Mac OS

Answer (score 3):

A classic user click triggers `mousedown` and `mouseup`.
The time between the two is usually somewhere **~50ms.**
In that short period of time, the browser might be busy due to processes fired by mousedown and **event bubbling and propagation**, specially if you bound too much handlers far up in the DOM tree like to `document` or `"html, body"`. Avoid that.

Also, `mouseup` might end up being never registered.
If some processes are taking too much time or you're simply too fast with your mouse, the `mouseup` might not be over the target element at the time it's triggered, therefore **never firing that event.**

Comment: This is not the problem. Nice explanation but it is not solution for me.

Comment: Can you get me some example of "never firing that event"? I never heard about it. Everything in JS is in queue....

Comment: @Čamo if you remove element on mousedown, for example?...

Comment: That make sense. But this is not about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was in local variables in the closure in animate call. var placeholderNode, var placeholderParent and var placeholderParentL. As I rewrite it to global state object problem seem to be less visible. But I am not sure if this is the root of issue.

Answer (score 0):

make it synchronous with the use of promise or async/await.
This link below contains documentation on async.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: I cant rewrite all the code to async for now. I want to know what happens there if all methods are done but mouseup is waiting for something.